# Regular search and "ask a new question" yield different results for already asked questions. Why is it?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, search

I kind of feel, I need to learn how to ask/search better on Stack Overflow.

I am sure there is a very good explanation behind as to why do I get quite different search results, with regular search for an answer, and when trying to ask a new question. What is it?

However, I have been wondering why is it, that the *"ask a new question"* option suggests far more already asked questions results. Moreover, they even seem to match my query much better than if I copy/paste the same query into the regular search bar.

What am I doing wrong?
(Yes, I have tried the search options :-)

Example:

Ask a new question option:

[image]

Regular search option:

[image]